# How can I loop through the entire array starting from any position?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array like this:

```
$arr = [0, 1, 2];
```

Now I get a user input, e.g.

```
$input = 1;
```

Depending on that input I want to loop through all array elements starting from the position of that input.

Example:

```
//Array: [0, 1, 2]
Input: 0 Output: 012
Input: 1 Output: 120
Input: 2 Output: 201
```

I don't know much about PHP so I tried a simple for loop:

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++)
{
    echo $x;
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work, so I'm stuck from where I have to go from here.

Comment: You can't get 120 from a simple loop, only 012 or 210.

Comment: Why, if you start from 1 and go to 0, would you expect to see 120? This question makes no sense.

Comment: The reason why I want that way because I have this code that runs accroding to user input. First I have an array that has the values ranging from 0,1 and 2 so if the user picks 0 it will display 012 but if the user picks 1 it will display 120 and lastly if the user picks 2 it will display 210.

Comment: @user9937 you're going to have to provide more info if you want an answer. That's a strange request, and you're probably going to have to hardcode that behavior. A simple loop can't go 1,2,0 without some very strange logic.

Comment: `if($userPick==0){echo 012;}` etc

Comment: sorry, if did not provide more info. Thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: create an array with the values you expect indexed in order... `array[0=>"012", 1=>"120", 2=>"201"]` then you can iterate over the array.

Comment: @EdCottrell I have to say the question was a bit weird and tricky, but I think with OP's comment it got clear now :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Just realized OP updated the question, which now conflicts with his or her comment about what should happen with input of 2. Your answer is very nice; +1 from me.

Comment: @user9937 Just to make sure: *"2 it will display 210."* don't you want `201`?

Answer (score 3):

So what you want to do is create an [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php).

Then set the position of the iterator with [`ArrayIterator::seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.seek.php) depending on which input you get. You can get the position easily with [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
$it->seek(array_search($input, $arr));
```

(If the input isn't found in the array `array_search()` simply returns FALSE, which then gets used as 0, means you just loop through the array)

Then you can simply loop through the amount of elements you have in the array with a for loop starting from the set position. And if you hit the end of the array you just rewind it:

```
//End of array?
if(!$it->valid()){
    //Start again
    $it->rewind();
}
```

Code

```
<?php

    $arr = [0, 1, 2];
    $input = 1;

    $it = new ArrayIterator($arr);
    $it->seek(array_search($input, $arr));

    for($i = 0, $length = count($arr); $i < $length; $i++){
        if(!$it->valid()){
            $it->rewind();
        }
        echo $it->current();
        $it->next();
    }

?>
```

output:

```
120
```

Comment: I've solved this already with two for loops one that is displaying the 12 and the second loop displaying only the zero and passing the function I've made. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user9937 You're welcome. Your question first was very vague, so I recommend you to see [ask]. Also you then provided a useful comment clarifying the question, but put information about your question into the question by editing it. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539309/how-can-i-loop-through-the-entire-array-starting-from-any-position/36539744?noredirect=1#comment60681747_36539309 just to get the last confusion cleared. (BTW: To get a quick overview of the site see [tour])

Answer (score -4):

```
foreach( [1,2,0] as $num ){
    echo $num;
}
```